# Many routes with Skobbler/Scout maps

Tags: skmaps

We have a requirement whereby we need to present rough pedestrian walking times between the users current location and approximately 12 locations, all on the screen at the same time.

We don't, by default need to present the routes on the map but we do wish to calculate these very quickly and update these values in real-time as the users location changes.

Now we could use RouteManager to calculate routes but these seems to be no real way of identifying which SKRouteInfo in the completed callback is associated with which route settings which was used to kick off a routing operation in the 1st place. Note that we are assuming here that it is safe to kick off multiple routing calls at the same time.

So, other than queueing up the routing requests one at a time and waiting for completion is there anyway of matching up the route info with the routing requests? Or is there another approach we could take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario is not supported.
When the route calculation process is executed only one single computation runs at a moment and the next computation is launched only when the first one is notifed as completelly finished.